# How to mute all video and audio in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a lot of videos on my e-commerce website all playing at the same time with audio enabled. I have to mute all videos by default to increase the quality of the user experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mute all videos by default, we hook the creation of a JavaScript function to the footer.

Every time your theme builds it's footer, the script JavaScript is added to the DOM.
The script than selects all the `video` elements and mutes them recursively.

So, go to the `Wordpress Admin` page, select `Appearance` > `Theme Editor`. On the right side of the page you should see `functions.php`. Click on it and add the following code at the bottom of the page:

```
# mute all videos by default
function mute_all_videos() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('video')).forEach(function(audio) {
        audio.muted = true;
  });
</script>
<?php
}

# hook to footer
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mute_all_videos' );
```